# array contents duplicate in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I wrote a simple program to check if the method of declaring a string affects if a string terminator is added by default or not, however, I noticed that the contents of one array are copied to another. Why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char *Name1 = "Name1";
    char Name2[] = "Name2";
    char Name3[] = {'N','a','m','e','3'};
    printf("Name1 = %lu\n",strlen(Name1));
    printf("%s\n",Name1);
    printf("Name2 = %lu\n",strlen(Name2));
    printf("%s\n",Name2);
    printf("Name3 = %lu\n",strlen(Name3));
    printf("%s\n",Name3);
    return 0;
}
# Name1 outputs 5 -> Name1
# Name2 outputs 5 -> Name2
# Name3 outputs 10 -> Name3Name2
```

Comment: `Name3` is not null terminated so `strlen` doesn't work.`printf` also expects a null terminated string with `%s`.

Comment: You answer your own question. Name3 doesn’t have a 0 on the end. However the behavior you got was not what you expected in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by:

- Passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: `strlen()` returns `size_t` and correct format specifyer to print that is `%zu`.
- Passed character sequence that is not null-terminated (`Name3`) to functions that expects strings (character sequence terminated by null-character).

It seems that `Name2` is **happened** to be allocated next to `Name3` and therefore readings from string-expecting functions slipped there.